# python 3 os.rename, can access img, but cant access filename

Tags: python

I'm trying to rename my images. They are in a different path than my script, but I can access them fine and get the exif data for example.

I'm then trying to rename them, but I always get *WinError 3, system cant find path xx*

```
path2 = (r"C:\Users\xx\PycharmProjects\Test01\imagetesting\_assets")

path_joined = os.path.join(path2, img)
os.rename(path2 + "\\" +  img, datetime_new + file_type_offset)
```

output:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3]:       
'C:\\\\Users\\\\xx\\\\PycharmProjects\\\\Test01\\\\imagetesting\\\\_assets\\\\IMG_3472.jpg' ->   
'2014/08/21_09/11/45.JPG'
```

€: I'm using pycharm 3.4.1 fulledition

€2: neither does this work:

```
path_joined = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\lnerlich\PycharmProjects\Test01\imagetesting\_assets', img)
os.rename(path_joined, datetime_new + file_type_offset)
```

€3: alright got the first problem, you can't rename your files using '/', but when I use '-' for example, I get WinError 32, files is in use by another process.

Comment: if you are testing this in IDLE you may find that the interpreter has opened them to do something with them and not closed them, or alternatively (as you said you were reading the EXIF data from them) you have opened them elsewhere in your script and not closed them again.

Comment: i have one method dedicated to reading the exif data. I call i.close at the end. There is no other process, i have checked with Process Explorer

Comment: ok, i'm not sure whats causing that then, but i notice you seem to be passing the full path for the first argument of the rename, but only the filename for the second, could you try it with the full path?

Comment: os.rename(path2, path2 + '\\' + datetime_new + file_type_offset)

yes, i have tried that by now ;-) Same error unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I expect that Windows is treating those forward slashes in '2014/08/21_09/11/45.JPG' as path separators, so replace them with another char, eg '-'.